# How to show a specific page in MERN only when user has logged in

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

What I want is to show about us page with users info upon logging in else redirect the user to login page.Now when i try to visit about us page without login in, I am sent to login page, But even after logging in I am still being sent to login page.
about.js code(frontend)

```
import React,{useState,} from 'react';
import {ToastContainer,toast} from "react-toastify";
import axios from "axios";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {

  const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password,setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();  // useHistory is now useNavigate

  const submitted = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
      const user = await axios.post('/login',{email:email,password:password});
      // console.log(user.data.userDetails);
      // console.log(user);
      if(user.status===400){                        //cors error not solved (proxy added in package.json file)
        // console.log("Error");
        toast.error("Invalid Credentials", {
          position: "top-right",
          autoClose: 5000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
        });
      }else if(user.status===200){
        /* 
          console.log(email+"\n"+password);
        */
        navigate("/");  // useHistory is now useNavigate
      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
     <div className="login-container">
     <div className="toastcontainer"><ToastContainer></ToastContainer></div>
     <form onSubmit={(e)=>{submitted(e)}} class="form" method="POST">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div class="inputs">
            <input value={email} onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)} type="text" required name="userName" id="userName" />
            <label htmlfor="userName">User Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs">
            <input value={password} onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password" required name="pass" id="pass" />
            <label htmlfor="pass">Password</label>
        </div>
          <input type="submit" value="login" class="submit-button" />
          <a href="#forgotPass" class="forgotPassword">Forgot Password</a>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="forgotPass">
        <form action="" class="form" method="get">
            <a href='#'  class="close" > &times; </a>   { /*&times will produce a cross(x)  */ } 
            <h3>Reset Password</h3>
            <div class="inputs">
                <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" />
                <label for="email">Email</label>
              </div>
          <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </form>
     </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Authentication middleware code:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../model/usersScheme");

const Authenticate = async (req,res,next) => {
    try{
        const token = req.cookies.jwtoken;
        const verifyingToken = jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRET_KEY);

        const rootUser = await User.findOne({_id:verifyingToken._id,"tokens.token":token})

        if(!rootUser){
            throw new Error ("User does not exist") 
        }
        req.token = token;
        req.rootUser = rootUser;
        req.userId = rootUser._id;

        next();
    }catch(error){
        console.log("in authenticate\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"+error);
        res.status(401).send(error);
    }
}

module.exports = Authenticate;
```

Route.js code:

```
router.get("/about",authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    res.send(req.rootUser);
    // ("Form about us page");

})
module.exports = router;
```

This is the error i get on console
**loadaboutUs
Error: Request failed with status code 401**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz5aM.png)

Answer (score -1):

this is not the best way to do Authentication as MERN developer instead you have better to use cookies to get authentication info from first get request ,
you can do that easily with help of passport.js ,
Good luck...